# 404 error page not redirected to custom page using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My htaccess rule to redirect 404 error to custom page isn't working.
I put the below code:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404.php
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule index\.html$   index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I used both - **ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404.php** & **ErrorDocument 404 /404.php**

Pls let me know if anyone have solution

Comment: maybe that module isn't loaded? Try removing your commands from the `if` statement

Comment: use SSH `apachectl -M` to check if this  module is actually loaded on your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/404/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <YourRelativePathToPHPFile>/404.php [L]
```

Here,The ErrorDocument redirects all 404s to a specific URL

The Rewrite rules map that URL to your actual 404.php script. The RewriteCond regular expressions can be made more generic if you want, but I think you have to explicitly define all ErrorDocument codes you want to override.

Comment: Here,The ErrorDocument redirects all 404s to a specific URL.